# How to set %origin% in oauth2.json

Tags: oauth-2.0, opensocial, apache-shindig

In shindig, while configuring OAuth gadget details in OAuth2.json, we need to give %origin% and %context% as part of gadget url and redirect url.

Ex:

"%origin%%contextRoot%/gadgets/oauth2/oauth2_google_shared2.xml" : {
         "googleAPI" : {
            "clientName"          : "googleApi_shared_client",
            "allowModuleOverride" : "true"
         }
      },

"redirect_uri"  : "%origin%%contextRoot%/gadgets/oauth2callback",

Can anybody help me is there any way to configure these values in SHINDIG so that these values will be applied for all the remaining entries in OAuth2.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Those values are automatically replaced by the code in shindig.  There is a filter in shindig which extracts the values from an incoming request and then uses them when needed.